# the running time from the programmcode

Tags: java, python, algorithm, parallel-processing, sum

I need your help. Could you help me please.

Input: Array A with n natural numbers.

```
count = 0
for each subset S of 4 elements of A do:
  sum = "sumFormula" from i = 0 to 3  S[i]
  for i from 0 to n-1 do:
        if sum == A[i]:
            count = count+1
return count.
```

I didn't understand it. What time does it take?

My idea: I think it has exponential runtime, because when I double the input size it squares. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the complexity of the algorithm is hidden.

In particular:

> for each subset S of 4 elements in A

How are these subsets determined?
There are 2^n possible subsets of a set with n elements.
Simply that first step might be the cause of the exponential runtime.

The remainder of the algorithm is essentially figuring out the sum of each of those subsets. That won't affect runtime much.